# need help making it so that there is a download for a c# file in HTML

Tags: c#, html

I tried to make it so that when the user clicks a button they automatically download the c# file. This is the code I used:

`<a href="Main.cs" download="test_image"><button type="button"> Download </button>`

Whenever the user clicks the download button though, it just shows them the code from the file. Is it possible to make it so that the user automatically downloads the file. No website I have found helps with this problem.

Comment: How `download` is treated is up to the browser and user settings. What you posted is an *unterminated* `<a>` tag though, containing  a button that doesn't seem to do anything. Even with a proper `a` though, if the browser is configured to open a file instead of saving it, that's what the browser will do

Comment: The MDN site explains [how the download attribute works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes). How the file is returned matters too. If *your web site* returns the file with a `Content-Disposition: inline` you're actually telling the browser to open instead of save.

Comment: If you have control of the server, you can set the `Content-Disposition` header to "attachment". This indicates to the browser that the file should be downloaded instead of displayed. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the `Content-Disposition` header of the file to "attachment". To do this in C#, you can add the following line of code at the beginning of your `Main` method:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Main.cs");
```

This will set the "Content-Disposition" header to "attachment" and specify the filename as "Main.cs". When the user clicks the download button, the browser will prompt them to save the file instead of displaying it.

Alternatively, if you're using ASP.NET, you can use the `FileContentResult` method to return the file as a downloadable content result, like this:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Main.cs"));
    string fileName = "Main.cs";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Then, you can link to this action method from your download button:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "ControllerName")"><button type="button">Download</button></a>
```

Replace "ControllerName" with the name of the controller that contains the `DownloadFile` action method.